# How to use the "Of" lenses? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, lenses

I want to write:

```
minimum $ map _x elems
```

using lenses. I want to use the `minimumOf` lens, but I can't figure out how to use it from its type.

I'm looking for something like

```
elems ^.. minimumOf x
```

but it does not type check:

```
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> let elems = [(1,2),(3,4)] :: [(Double, Double)]
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> elems ^.. minimumOf _1

<interactive>:62:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’
                  with ‘[(Double, Double)]
                        -> Const (Data.Monoid.Endo [a]) [(Double, Double)]’
    Expected type: Getting (Data.Monoid.Endo [a]) [(Double, Double)] a
      Actual type: (a -> Const (Data.Monoid.Endo [a]) a) -> Maybe a0
    Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:62:1)
    Possible cause: ‘minimumOf’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(^..)’, namely ‘minimumOf _1’
    In the expression: elems ^.. minimumOf _1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:minimumOf) seems reasonably clear on the usage -- how would you improve it?

`minimumOf` isn't a lens (or traversal or anything) -- it takes a fold (or traversal or lens or something -- but it's not useful to use it with a lens, because you're taking the minimum of exactly one thing) and looks for the minimum value that it focuses on in a structure. E.g.

```
λ> minimumOf (traverse . _1) [(1,'a'),(2,'b')]
Just 1
```

It generalizes the Prelude function `minimum` -- which always takes a list -- to a function which takes any sort of value, along with instructions for getting a bunch of things out of that value, and computes the minimum of those things.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I was looking at the old version of the documentation.